# Windows Services access denied

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have write a Windows Services with c#. This services, can run automatically every minutes one or more batch file. The batch file move file from a local folder to a remote folder.

Now if I try to run file .batch manually it works, but if I try to run batch file from Windows Services I have a problem, the log file have Access Denied.
So this is the batch file:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set LOCAL_PATH="C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001"
set INSTRUMENT_NAME=41IT.Poros.PORO001
echo Copying files to MES server...
robocopy %LOCAL_PATH% \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\EXPORT *.* /R:2 /W:5 /MOV /log+:\\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\LOGS\LabInstr.log

echo Transfer complete.
endlocal
```

This is the log file of remote folder:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Dec 11 10:39:18 2014

   Source : C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001\
     Dest : \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:2 /W:5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       2    C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001\
        New File               0    test.txt
2014/12/11 10:39:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:23 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:28 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.


ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.

        New File               0    test4444.txt
2014/12/11 10:39:28 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:33 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:38 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.


ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.

2014/12/11 10:39:38 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:43 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:49 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.


ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         2         0         0         0         2         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:30   0:00:00                       0:00:30   0:00:00

   Ended : Thu Dec 11 10:39:49 2014
```

If I see the windows services in "manage application widnwos" I see this:

[image]

I would not the problem is the account of the WindowsServices that not have a permission for copy file. Because if I use same code of Windows Services into a "Consolle Application" in C# it works.

[image]

Comment: Please supply us with following info: When installing the service, you have supply a user under whom the service will run. Has this user adequate rights?

Comment: I install the services throught prompt so I use this code:
InstallUtil.exe ScriptServices.exe.
The services is on LocalSystem, I think the error is this, but I don't know how assign the user

Comment: Right Click the service => Propertiers => Tabpage 'Log on'. Here you can supply the correct user.

Comment: I have just edit my answer and I have add the print screen. I see Local System. I think that information is not correct. I logon in my computer with my user: mcastrio and password

Comment: Then you choose "This account" and supply the correct user & password.

Comment: I try to insert an account but I select browser bottom, then I insert "mcastrio" in text box, then "Check name" but I have an error message "Object cannot be found....."

Comment: Clicking 'OK' might help. If your user is correct you should return back to the previous window.

Comment: OK, I have fixed the problem. I have find, my user then the script works.